# Node.js console.log() gives unpredictable answer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This is a function to search test questions and match the answer given by the user and stored in the database. Console.log() displays all 6 questions but in random order. And the value of num is 6 for each iteration. if I do console.log(num) without finding anything from the database then I correctly display values 1,2,3,4,5,6.

```
function(req,res){
    var arr = [2,1,3,4,1,4],score=0, num=0;
    Test.find({name:req.params.testnum}).
    populate({
        path: 'question',
        model: 'Testques'
    }).
    exec(function(err,test){
        console.log(test)
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send('DB error');
        }
        else{
            arr.forEach(myFunction)
            function myFunction(value){
                num+=1;
                Testques.find({Serialnum:num},function(err,ques){
                    console.log(num);
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log(ques);
                        console.log(ques[0].answer);
                        if(ques[0].answer == value){
                            score=score+4;
                            console.log(score);
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: the error here seems to be that your function doesn't have a name...

Comment: The problem is that `Testques.find` is an asynchronous process, but `forEach` is not. So `num+=1` will be executed all six times (once for each pass of the `forEach`) before any of your `Testques.find` queries have finished. So when they do finally finish, `num` is already at `6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with what [CRice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6293409/crice) has to say about it. Inside the else of the callback, you're trying to run a synchronous `forEach` loop, but you're running an asynchronous block of code ( namely : `Testques.find` ) inside it, which would not work the way you wish it to work.

An elegant solution could be, to promisify your Mongoose calls, ( using promisifying utils available ), and then, once promisified, either use Promise.all to resolve the arrays of these queued up promises of `Testques.find` that you may push inside it.

Otherwise, you can also proceed as follows : Move your function inside the argument of the `forEach` to another method outside this method's scope, and then use basi knowledge of recursion to achieve what you wish to. It should resemble somewhat to this :

```
function cbIterator($index, arr, num, score) {
    if ($index < arr.length) {
        const value = arr[$index];
        num++;
        Testques.find({ Serialnum: num }, function (err, ques) {
            console.log(num);
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log(ques);
                console.log(ques[0].answer);
                if (ques[0].answer === value) {
                    score = score + 4;
                    console.log(score);
                }
                cbIterator($index + 1, arr, num, score);
            }
        });
    }
    return;
}

function myTestFunction(req, res) {
    // A bit of ES6. Feel free to replace the const / let with var if you are not comfortable with those
    const arr = [2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 4];
    let score = 0, num = 0;
    Test.find({ name: req.params.testnum })
        .populate({
            path: 'question',
            model: 'Testques'
        }).exec(function (error, test) {
            if (error) {
                res.status(500).send('DB Error');
            } else {
                let $index = 0;
                cbIterator($index, arr, num, score);
            }
        });
}
```